# Recurrence Relation with exponential variables (taking log)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Solve the recurrence relation
\begin{align}
a_n &= a_{n-1} ^ 3 \cdot a_{n-2} ^ 2 \\
a_0 &= a_1 = 2
\end{align}

Taking the logarithm of both sides seem helpful, but I could not continue. Is it valid to write characteristic equation like in the ordinary recurrence relations in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea was good
$$a_n = a_{n-1} ^ 3 \, a_{n-2} ^ 2 \implies\log(a_n)=3\log(a_{n-1})+2\log(a_{n-2})$$
Let $b_n=\log(a_n)$ to make
$$b_n=3b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}$$ The characteristic equation being $r^2=3r+2$ gives for the roots
$r_\pm=\frac{1}{2} \left(3\pm\sqrt{17}\right)$. So
$$b_n=c_1 \left(\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}2 \right)^n+c_2 \left(\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}2 \right)^n$$ Apply the conditions $b_0=b_1=\log(2)$ and go back to $a_n$ to get
$$a_n=2^{c_n}$$ where $$ c_n=\frac 1{34}\Bigg[\left(17+\sqrt{17} \right)\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}2 \right)^n+\left(17-\sqrt{17} \right)\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}2 \right)^n\Bigg]$$ and the first terms of the sequence are
$$\{2,2,32,131072,2305843009213693952,\cdots\}$$

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at the first few elements (calculated or in general) and then find out a closed formula. We can start by calculating $a_2$ using the general formula and then trying to give a closed formula only using $a_1$:

$$a_2 = a_1^3 \cdot a_0^2 = a_1^5$$
Last equality holds as $a_0=a_1$.

Let's continue calculating the next few iterations:
\begin{align}
a_3 &= a_2^3 \cdot a_1^2 = (a_1^5)^3 \cdot a_1^2 = a_1^{17} \\
a_4 &= a_3^3 \cdot a_2^2 = (a_1^{17})^3 \cdot (a_1^5)^2 = a_1^{61} \\
a_5 &= a_4^3 \cdot a_3^2 = (a_1^{61})^3 \cdot (a_1^{17})^2 = a_1^{217} \\
\end{align}

In general we get the result of $a_n = a_1^{f(n)}$ where $f(n)$ is the sequence corresponding to http://oeis.org/A007483, which is the number of subsequences of $[1,...,2n+1]$ in which each odd number has an even neighbor. The even neighbor must differ from the odd number by exactly $1$.

So basically by taking the logarithm you get that $\log_2 a_n = f(n)$ with $f(n)$ the above sequence.